# .Net test multiple connections for AD authentication using system.web.security (membership)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory, asp.net-membership

Most of our .net IIS webapps use the System.Web.Security in .net to validate user logins in AD. However, during a company transition period, we currently have 4 AD domain controllers. I am looking for a way to test the AD user login against other AD connection strings in the event that one is down or that a user is using a different domain password.

Our code is just:

```
bool isValidAdUser = Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

And the connection string is set inside the Membership tag in web.config. How I can I add more connection strings?

Comment: If you want to test the 4 controllers one time, I guess you could just insert each connection string manually and test them one by one. If you are looking for a more automated approach, maybe share some more details about how you want to do this. Do you want to publish the app to four different subdomains or something for testing? Or do you want to test this locally?

Comment: We have two separate domains, one from an old company and one from a new. The goal would be to automatically check the user's login against each for the next year and if either is valid, log into the app. Then each domain has a backup controller for when one is under updates or maintenance. I am not sure how to continue to use the built-in membership ValidateUser to check against more than connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the connection string of a `MembershipProvider` at runtime.

You can however implement a custom [`MembershipProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membershipprovider) that delegates its method execution to the different Active Directory membership providers registered in the `web.config` file, where each of these has its own connection string to the corresponding domain.

Consider a custom `MembershipProvider` - named `DelegatingMembershipProvider` - that implements its `ValidateUser` call by looping over each registered Active Directory membership provider until the first one of these returns `true` or all of them `false`.

About checking whether the given domain controller is online; you might wrap the `ValidateUser` call with a `try/catch`, assuming that this call towards an offline domain controller fails as such - *you'll have to check that one*.

Below code shows how such a `MembershipProvider` can look like. Find more details at [Implementing a Membership Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100)).

*For brevity, the code just shows the essential parts.*

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class DelegatingMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public override bool ValidateUser (string username, string password)
        {
            foreach (MembershipProvider provider in Membership.Providers)
            {
                if (provider.Name != Name)
                {
                    bool isValid = provider.ValidateUser(userName, password)
                    if (isValid)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return false
        }

        // Other methods go here.
    }
}
```

You register this `DelegatingMembershipProvider` in `web.config` as below. Notice that this custom membership provider needs to be set as the default one.

```
<membership>
  <providers defaultProvider="DelegatingMembershipProvider">

    <add name="DelegatingMembershipProvider"
      type="YourNamespace.DelegatingMembershipProvider, YourAssembly"
      /> 
 
    <add name="AD1MembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web ..."
      connectionStringName="AD1"
      connectionUsername="domain1\user" 
      connectionPassword="password"
      />

    <add name="AD2MembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web ..."
      connectionStringName="AD2"
      connectionUsername="domain2\user" 
      connectionPassword="password"
      />        
  </providers>
</membership>

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="AD1" connectionString="..." />
  <add name="AD2" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```